# Passing value form XSLT to HTML

Tags: html, xslt

I have a question concerning XSLT,
I use a XML file generated by an external software and show the result in a HTML page. To do the transformation, I use XSLT. 
In this last one I create a link to a new HTML page for an ID.

```
<div >
<xsl:variable name="vrtfTokens">
<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
<xsl:with-param name="pText" select="Hit_def"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:element name="a">
**<xsl:attribute name="href">display.hmtl?value=<xsl:value-of 
select="ext:node-set($vrtfTokens)/*[4]"/>**
</xsl:attribute>                                
<xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($vrtfTokens)/*[4]"/>
</xsl:element>
<br/>
</div>
```

Ma question is the following one : is it possible to pass this value to a new HTML file and see a  result in this new page, for example  just display the value??

Comment: So you want to reparse the output HTML as XML and apply XSLT to generate another HTML page? If so, why not just do it all in one step?

Comment: not exactly. In fact the XSLT generate the html page with in this page the href link, I would like when I clic on the link to open a new page (display.html in the code) with only the value of the link (for example a ID). it is more clear?

Comment: If I understand your question, the problem isn't really related to XSLT, it is asking how to load a specific piece of data in an html page. In that case, it really depends on other parameters (languages available, client- vs server, etc).

Generally, I agree with Tyler: if the vrtfToken is set based on some state defined by the original request (like a url parameter or cookie) then why not just output the data on the initial request?

Answer (score 0):

With this xslt you created a link with your ID. 
So now in your new page you can obtain your ID with the method Get in php or 
if you use servlets you can parse your url and send a parameter Id to an other xslt file.